# Visual Studio .NET Object Explorer language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2010, and I notice when using the Object Explorer everything comes up as VB.Net, and it'd really be a lot more comfortable for me if it were C#. It's going to give me nightmares.

Note I am working in a ASP.NET Website Project (connected to IIS localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, if you don't want to reset **ALL** of your settings:

- Export just your Object Browser settings by de-selecting all of the options in the Import and Export Settings dialog, then checking General Settings-->Object Browser Options.
- Open the `.settings` file you exported in Notepad (or your favorite text editor)
- Change the `<PropertyValue name="DefaultPresentationLanguage">` setting to `VC#` (notice the V in front).
- Import your settings back in and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your default presentation language has changed.

> Go to Tools-> Import and Export Settings -> Select the option to reset
>   all -> Then a window will pop asking for the language -> Select C#
>   there.

Also check out the link [Change Default Presentation Langauge](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/05/16/how-to-change-default-language-in-visual-studio.aspx)